# AngularJs -- Access to XMLHttpRequest has been blocked by CORS policy

Tags: angularjs, cors, same-origin-policy

error :

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8080/api/v1/locations' from origin 'http://localhost:8000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

I test the get method in a request.http file of WebStorm and in Postman and that work , but that doesn't work in my Angularjs project .
(I get from a Spring boot java project).

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
  app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
    $http.get("http://localhost:8080/api/v1/locations")
            .then(function(response) {
              $scope.result = response.data;
              console.log("OK:", response.data);
            }).catch(function(response) {
              console.log("ERROR:", response);
    });
  });
```

my get function return something like this in postman

```
[
 {
   "datetime": "2019-01-10T19:00:00.000+0000",
"user": {
  "firstName": "thr",
  "lastName": "an",
  "id": 1
},
"speed": 0.0,
"latitude": 37.421998333333335,
"longitude": -122.08400000000002,
"id": 1
},

{
   "datetime": "2019-01-10T19:01:00.000+0000",
"user": {
  "firstName": "thr",
  "lastName": "an",
  "id": 1
},
"speed": 1.575,
"latitude": 37.42198333333335,
"longitude": -122.080000000002,
"id": 2
}
]
```

the console : https://i.top4top.io/p_1507d02621.jpg

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Postman usually doesn't use or consider the CORS header. The browser on the other hand needs it and if its missing, you get this error.
In your backend code, you should whitelist the domain which you use to request the data. In your case this would be `http://localhost:8080`. 
I hope this makes sense.

Comment: yes this is working thank you ,I add " @CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:8000", maxAge = 3600)" in my case to my Java Spring boot controller .

Answer (score 0):

Add a `.catch` block to log errors:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
    $http.get("http://localhost:8080/api/v1/locations")
      .then(function(response) {
        $scope.result = response.data;
        console.log("OK:", response.data);
    }).catch(function(response) {
        console.log("ERROR:", response);
    });
});
```

Comment: this is my console https://i.top4top.io/p_1507d02621.jpg